# Why don't any Linux distros have a built-in ability to edit media metadata?

Tags: audio, video, file-metadata, multimedia, mediaplayer

In Windows you can simply right-click a media file and edit its metadata - no additional software needed. Why is this ability absent in Linux? Is there some inherent technical limitation in Linux that prevents this?

Comment: Is the question actually "why?", or is it "how may I...?" (which may possibly be both easier to answer and more useful to you)?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has paid developers to implement features. Open Source is often written by volunteers in their spare time. You're welcome to sponsor someone to add this feature to your favourite desktop environment.

Last but not least many certain media formats/codecs where metadata can be edited have been protected by patents, so there's a risk that even if such a feature is to be implemented, distros won't pick it up.

Comment: No Unix-based OS has this feature, even MacOS cannot do it. There seems to be some issue with Unix/Linux that prevents it.